# Wireless does not work on Levovo G530 (Broadcom 4312) ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, 13.10, broadcom

I am having problems getting my wifi to work on a Lenovo G530.

The output of `lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4` is the following:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
```

It shows that the wifi is disabled by hardware switch but I have already verified that it is ON.

`rfkill list` is:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN

    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN

    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN

    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

unblocking command didn't help.

I tried using both the "`bcmwl-kernel-source`" and "`firmware-b43-installer` `b43-fwcutter`" packages (not at the same time), but the same problem persists.  I installed them both manual and via Synaptic.

Comment: What driver is currently in use on the Broadcom card? It should show in `lspci -v`. I had to use the `bcma-pci-bridge` driver on mine...

Comment: For more info, try lspci -vvnn -s 04:00.0

Comment: Should I try to re-install the entire system?  It's as though the hardware switch is permanently in the off position.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the firmware-b43-lpphy-installer package for your chip.

Comment: When I try to install it, I get a message saying that firmware-b43-installer now supports my device (as well as the release info).

Answer (score 0):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and let us hear your report.

If it is still not working, carefully check the position of the wireless switch and/or key combination: http://download.lenovo.com/express/HT071417.html Check to see if any modules are loaded that translate key presses to action. We suspect *ideapad-laptop* is loaded and possibly *acer-wmi*; confirm:

```
lsmod
```

If it is loaded, remove *acer-wmi*:

```
sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

Any improvement? If it helps, we can blacklist *acer-wmi*.

Comment: I am getting the same results.  It just doesn't want to turn ON - I have verified everything though several times.  The new driver is active when I look under "additional drivers".  As an FYI, the wireless worked when I had Windows installed.

Comment: Does rfkill list all look any different?

Comment: no - it looks exactly like I have above

Comment: What? Certainly the part about brcmwl should be gone if you removed it as I suggested. No??

Comment: my bad - sorry!  Yes, it did change.  I've been running the command so many times today :) here's what I have now:0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I really appreciate your help!  The acer-wmi module was not loaded but the ideapad-laptop was loaded.  I removed it and now get 1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: Please reboot so we have a clean slate and run: dmesg > wifi.txt && lsmod >> wifi.txt. Find the file wifi.txt in your user directory and paste it here and give us the link in your reply: http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Here's the output-> http://paste.ubuntu.com/6798128/

Comment: Should I try to re-install the entire system? It's as though the hardware switch is permanently in the off position.

Comment: It sure looks as if it is. I suggest you first try a live DVD or USB for 12.04 and then, try again, the install media for 13.10. Is it still hard blocked?